# Trouble with loading json files into template.html using angular factories

Tags: json, angularjs, fetch, factory

I am trying to understand how to use factories and struggling to understand a few things.

I want to load json file into template but I am hitting the wall

```
myApp.factory('getUsersFactory',['$http',function($http){
   return {
     getUsers: function(callback){
       $http({method: 'JSONP', url: "users.json?query=?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query="+ $scope.searchString}).success(callback);
     }
   }
}]);

myApp.factory('Tester', function($resource) {
  return $resource('users.json');
});

myApp.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope, Tester, getUsersFactory) {

  // Teens are from static json file
  $scope.users = Tester.query();

  // Adults are from REST API
  $scope.teens = getUsersFactory.query();

});
```

If you will have look in my example you will see that I am trying to load from users.json file content to main.html

I would like to be able to load multiple json files into main.html

PLUNKER [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjZxFfgoFt8rshL15ncw?p=preview)

Could you please advice me with example how to do this correctly.

Comment: Would you mind skimming down the Plunker to a minimal example that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to change your `getUsersFactory` factory, because you don't have there `$scope`:

  myApp.factory('getUsersFactory',['$http',function($http){
     return {
       getUsers: function(searchStr, callback){
         $http({method: 'JSONP', url: "users.json?query=?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query="+ searchStr}).success(callback);
       }
     }
  }]);

As you can see, i added one more parameter - `searchStr`.

- You need to call function `getUsers()` of your factory `getUsersFactory`. Actually problem is next: function `query()` is not defined in your factory `getUsersFactory`. 
  Actually seems it works even if call
   `$scope.teens = getUsersFactory.getUsers();` - without params.

So, answer to your question - use function of factory which you defined: `getUsersFactory.getUsers()`

#### Changed plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/xIzd8Zyg0hzMgbPCzEfj?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It seems that it is not working as it is loading from 

myApp.factory('Tester', function($resource) {
  return $resource('users.json');
});